# Component based UI framework for Ruby/Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

Greetings all,

I am coming from Java background and I have used frameworks like Wicket,GWT,ZK..etc.I was just wondering is there any similar framework for Rails/Ruby where I can handle the UI level purely using Ruby ? (like GWT,ZK)?

Comment: So you don't want to bother learning HTML + CSS?

Comment: I am newbie,but I guess Rails uses something similar to  JSP rendering, and it seems kind of going backward once you used frameworks like above.Atleast a component-based-framework like Wicket/Tapestry would do, where I have to do HTML,CSS myself.

Comment: It's not a full solution like you're looking for, but you may be interested in [Apotomo](http://apotomo.de/), a MVC widget framework.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some things to look at:

- [Trellis](https://github.com/bsbodden/trellis) is a Ruby framework inspired by Tapestry.
- GWT could be used with Rails - there is a project called [gwt-rails](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-rails/) that makes it easier. You'd still be writing the client side code in Java though.
- [mustache](https://github.com/defunkt/mustache) is templating framework that can work with Ruby/Rails.
- [HAML](http://haml-lang.com/)/[SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) still requires HTML/CSS but it makes it a little easier to deal with.

Comment: Trellis looks interesting, but isn't actively developed any more? At least github shows no activity for the past 3 years.